# String formatting

Tags: python-3.x, python

I have a list filter = ['a', 'b', 'c']. I need to frame the following string out of the list
"item -a item -b item -c". Which is the most efficient way to do this? Usually the list filter contains 100 to 200 items and each would be of length 100 - 150. Wouldn't that lead to overflow? And what is the maximum length of the string supported?

Comment: Don't use `filter` as variable name. "filter" is a Python function.

Comment: So many things are Python builtins that it's hard not to step on them now and then.  It generally only affects the block of code it's in, so rather than trying to memorize every builtin function name, it's reasonably harmless to just avoid the ones you know and use, and rename variables later on if you miss one and need to use it.

Comment: There really aren't that many built-in functions. Just over 80.

Comment: *special* functions like `filter` usually are highlighted by the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner way to do this:

```
filter = ['a', 'b', 'c']
" ".join(["item -%s" % val for val in filter])
```

This works fine with large arrays, eg. `filter = ['a'*1000] * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)** (I believe `join` is the same in Python 3.0):

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c']
>>> print ' item -'.join([''] + l)
>>> ' item -a item -b item -c'

>>> print ' item -'.join([''] + l).lstrip(' ') # eat the leading space
>>> 'item -a item -b item -c'
```

Comment: You probably want to trim excess whitespace off the result too.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger, yes we can trim the leading space. `join(l)` won't give the result that Prabhu wants. The string would start `'a item...'` instead of `'item -a...'`

Answer (score 0):

Again with `join`

But with `f-string`, this would be:

```
filter = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(" ".join([f"item -{val}" for val in filter]))
```

And as mentioned, avoid using keywords to name your vars.